# center align menu in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Already try other solutions from this community, but nothing seams to work!!
I want to horizontally center the menu. The "logo" is left align on top of it.

Here is the code (no changes to css that matter to this):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

    <div class="col-lg-2">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-8">

        <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" />

        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/menu/123.png" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/menu/456.png" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/menu/789.png" />
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>      

    <div class="col-lg-2">            
    </div>

</nav>
```

Edit: This solved the problem

```
ul {
    width: 825px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this `<div class="col-lg-8">` to this `<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-push-2 center-block">`

Get rid of the two empty `<div class="col-lg-2">`

Comment: Thanks for the time but it did not work!! I just want to center the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this codes,

[Bootstrap Centered Navigation](http://www.bootply.com/mQh8DyRfWY)

[Bootstrap Centered Menu](http://www.bootply.com/101681)

Answer (score -1):

well, solved:

```
ul {
    width: 825px;
    margin: auto;
}
```